# How to mock AngleSharp's HttpRequester to provide static content in unit tests?

Tags: moq, xunit.net, anglesharp

I am working on an application that includes a web scraper for gathering data and would like to verify that a particular service (which in the future will grow to several services) is performing the correct business logic given an expected HTML DOM tree is returned to it.

Rather than performing actual HTTP requests each time a test is run, I would prefer to "mock" this out by providing a static document for the test and returning a pre-defined HTML document. I'd prefer instead for my unit test to reflect "Given this HTML document, verify the output is correct business wise" which does not need to include AngleSharp's HTTP request.

Here's how I load the document now, which I have placed into a "wrapper" service that I can then inject into my service through dependency injection:

```
var angleSharpConfig = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
var angleSharpContext = BrowsingContext.New(angleSharpConfig);
var document = await angleSharpContext.OpenAsync(url);
```

I see that there is a `LoaderOptions` object that can be passed to `WithDefaultLoader`, but it does not seem to provide a way to mock the HTTP request. There does seem to possibly be a way to do this with the `With` method on the default configuration object, however I am struggling to see how to sanely do this.

Other suggestions for alternate approaches are welcome, as well - due to my inexperience I may be attempting to skin a cat that needn't be skinned at all.

Answer (score 0):

Hooo boy, was this one a doozy. And to be quite honest, I'm probably still using a chainsaw when a hacksaw may have done just well enough here, so I'd still welcome constructive feedback on my "solution" here.

In order to allow AngleSharp to "do its thing" and return me a static `IDocument` of the file I have saved to disk, I had to do a few things (some of which I started on when I wrote this questions, others I figured out the hard way):

1. Wrap the call to AngleSharp in a service that DI can then inject (and I can mock)
2. Make said call on service take a `IRequester` parameter, normally just pass `null` and use `new DefaultHttpRequester()` when null
3. Create my own implementation of `IRequester`, but make `RequestAsync` and `SupportsProtocol` `virtual` so that Moq can do its thing. Easiest way to do this (in VS Code) is to right click on the interface on the same line as your fake class name, and have the IDE auto-generate the implementation. Every method throws an exception, but it fulfills the contract.
4. Do a two-stage dance prior to calling the unit under test:

   - Create an instance of your AngleSharp wrapper class (true implementation, not the interface or a mock), then create a bare minimum mock of `IRequester`, mocking Address, Headers, and Content (reading the HTML file from disk) and pass it to the wrapper method, getting back a fully-fledged legit `IDocument` of the HTML file on disk.
   - Create a mock of your AngleSharp wrapper class and mock the method, telling it to return the `IDocument` from the previous step, then provide this for your unit under test.

GAH. This is insane and I now see why this question is the first result on Google :)

Anyway, for specifics, here's a rough sketch of the code I came up with to solve this:

Test:

```
[Fact]
public async void ItShouldDoSomething() {
    using(var autoMock = AutoMock.GetLoose()) {
        var mockedWrapper = autoMock.Mock<IAngleSharpWrapper>();
        var fakeDocument = await GetFakeDocument();
        mockedWrapper.Setup(x => x.OpenUrlAsync(It.IsAny<IRequester>())).ReturnsAsync(fakeDocument);
        autoMock.Provide(mockedWrapper);

        var sut = autoMock.Create<ClassYouAreTesting>();

        var data = await sut.LoadData();

        //Perform your assertions here
    }
}
```

Associated stubbing and mocking methods:

```
private async Task<IDocument> GetFakeDocument() {
    var angleSharpWrapper = new AngleSharpWrapper();
    var requesterMock = GetFakeRequesterMock();
    return await angleSharpWrapper.OpenUrlAsync("http://askjdkaj", requesterMock.Object);
}

private Mock<FakeRequester> GetFakeRequesterMock() {
    var mockResponse = new Mock<IResponse>();
    mockResponse.Setup(x => x.Address).Returns(new Url("fakeaddress"));
    mockResponse.Setup(x => x.Headers).Returns(new Dictionary<string, string>());
    mockResponse.Setup(_ => _.Content).Returns(LoadFakeDocumentFromFile());
    var mockFakeRequester = new Mock<FakeRequester>();

    mockFakeRequester.Setup(_ => _.RequestAsync(It.IsAny<Request>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(mockResponse.Object);
    mockFakeRequester.Setup(x => x.SupportsProtocol(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);
    return mockFakeRequester;
}

private MemoryStream LoadFakeDocumentFromFile() {
    //Note: path below is relative to your output directory, so bin/Debug/etc.
    using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Path/To/Your/LocalFile.html")))
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        memoryStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
        fileStream.Read(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);

        return memoryStream;
    }
}
```

*Edit: Figured I should include the wrapper method around AngleSharp, too, that's kinda important:

```
public async Task<IDocument> OpenUrlAsync(string url, IRequester defaultRequester)
{
    if (defaultRequester == null) {
        defaultRequester = new DefaultHttpRequester();
    }

    var angleSharpConfig = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().With(defaultRequester);
    var angleSharpContext = BrowsingContext.New(angleSharpConfig);
    return await angleSharpContext.OpenAsync(url);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at AngleSharp's test base? There is already a similar method (`PageRequester`) which either reads from network (nothing on disk) or from disk. AngleSharp's own tests use this for integration purposes.

Comment: I tried looking through the tests, but admittedly I am not very good at doing so, because I kinda blindly pieced together this solution on my own. I'll take a peek when my feet are back in this codebase again!